# migrating broadleaf hsql to postgres

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb, broadleaf-commerce

I got some errors migrating from HSQL to PostgreSQL:

> 2017-07-31 17:52:14.953 ERROR 7577 --- [ost-startStop-1]   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: type "double" does not exist
>   2017-07-31 17:52:13.218 ERROR 7577 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: type "longvarchar" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have followed all the instructions detailed in https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/database-configuration/postgresql. It looks like you did not do the part to change the dialect for each persistence unit to be Postgres and it is still using HSQL.

Comment: The instructions are wrong, so solve it by adding the same core settings in the admin default.properties, thanks

Comment: The instructions are for a previous version, they even mention files that do not exist